# Is there a reason why Serverless cannot find my AWS Credentials within a Conda virtual environment?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy a lambda function to AWS using the Serverless framework. Everything appears to be working fine however when I run either command to deploy `sudo sls deploy` or `sudo serverless deploy` I get the following error.

I know the error message states that my AWS Credentials are not found but I am not sure why?

I have set them up according to the documentation on http://slss.io/aws-creds-setup with the Serverless Config Credentials

Steps I have taken to remedy this:

1. Rerun the `serverless config credentials --provider aws --key key --secret secret`
2. Tried adding `Profile:` into my YAML file as 'default' and the name of the user in AWS.
3. Used the export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= **and** export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= to set credentials in my environment.

I have noted my `.aws/credentials` file exists, but it's not within my virtual environment. I'm assuming because of this Serverless unable to find the credentials but I haven't seen this documented anywhere.

Am I missing something?

````
[sudo] password for osboxes: 
Serverless: Generated requirements from /home/osboxes/spacy-med/requirements.txt in /home/osboxes/spacy-med/.serverless/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from /home/osboxes/spacy-med/.serverless/requirements/requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
 
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in our docs here: <http://slss.io/aws-creds-setup>.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              14.17.4
     Framework Version:         2.53.1
     Plugin Version:            5.4.3
     SDK Version:               4.2.6
     Components Version:        3.14.2```


  [1]: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials#setup-with-serverless-config-credentials-command
````

Answer (score 0):

Try running aws configure inside your conda environment:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html

Also, please do not run it using sudo, if you need to do that you have probably installed something incorrect.